# Rails + Redis subscribe returns an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, runtime-error

Rails 4 + Redis 3.0.4

When I trying to subscribe to channel with Redis:

```
$ rails c
irb(main):001:0> redis = Redis.new
=> #<Redis client v3.0.2 for redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0>
irb(main):002:0> redis.subscribe('test-channel')
```

It throws an error:

```
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:52:in `initialize'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:30:in `new'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:30:in `subscription'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:12:in `subscribe'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:2221:in `_subscription'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:1883:in `block in subscribe'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `block in synchronize'
from .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:1882:in `subscribe'
from (irb):2
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: See an example here: https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/examples/pubsub.rb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wild guess would be subscribe is expecting a block.

So pass a block, hint: use a do end block.

Like this:

```
$redis.subscribe('rubyonrails', 'ruby-lang') do |on|   
  on.message do |channel, msg|
   data = JSON.parse(msg)
   puts "##{channel} - [#{data['user']}]: #{data['msg']}"   
  end 
end
```